# Firebase cloud functions errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Greetings of the day to everyone,

So I'm having a really hard time with Firebase cause there's just so many versions and things going on. Its extremely complicated. I wanted to achieve some functionality which is not available through the client modular web 9 version.

So I have been trying to use the Cloud functions to just get the list of all the collections in a document.

My cloud function looks like this so far -

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { object } = require("firebase-functions/v1/storage");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addMessages = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = data.text;
    var test;
    const writeResult = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(original)

    const collections = await writeResult.listCollections();
    collections.forEach(collection => {
        console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection.id);
        test = collection.id;

    });
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message

    return { id: test }
});
```

I call this function on my front end simply like this --

```
const functions = getFunctions();
    const addMessage = httpsCallable(functions, 'addMessages');

    const Cloud = () => {
        addMessage({ docPath: `users/${userProfile.uid}` })
            .then(function (result) {
                var collections = result.data.collections;
                console.log(collections);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // Getting the Error details.
                var code = error.code;
                var message = error.message;
                var details = error.details;
                // ...
            });
    }
```

However, I get a 500 ERROR. I have checked the payload and everything, the data is being passed and the function is being called but there is some other kind of bug that I seem to be missing.

If anyone has any ideas please do let me know.

Comment: You can try adding function logs using `functions.logger` and checking in the GCP console or Firebase Functions console for logs

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're calling `addMessage` with an Object parameter and then trying to access it's payload by the `text` field of `data`, which is undefined. You could either pass `users/${userProfile.uid}` as a string parameter or assign `data.docPath` to `original`.

Also, `test` will only contain the last collection id, since it's being overwritten `forEach` of the collections. So, may I suggest you make `test` a string array and `push()` each collection id to it?

Finally, on the callback of `addMessage`, there is no data field to access in `result`. In the case you decide to use an array, `result` will simply be the array you returned from the cloud function.

P.S. I'm not sure I see a reason why this wouldn't work with the V9 modular SDK.